# new line in Random Access File in java

Tags: java, newline, randomaccessfile

Whenever using the 'writeBytes' method of `RandomAccessFile` in java,it writes the text in the same line in the file. How can I get to a new line with `RandomAccessFile` only? (No `BufferedReader`).

Comment: that is what javadoc says "The write starts at the current position of the file pointer". try writing new line character before writing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
 RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("e:\\demo.txt","rw");
 String originalString = "First line \nSeconf line \n";
 String updatedString = originalString.replace("\n","\r\n");
 file.writeBytes(updatedString);
```

Comment: Basically using '\r\n' escape sequence worked with it.Thanks a lot,friend!!

Answer (score 4):

You can write a line separator. In order to get the correct line separator for the currently running operating system, you'll have to look for the `line.separator` property. Something along these lines:

```
randomAccessFile.writeBytes(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: Your method is wrong. `write()` does not take in `String`. You should probably change it to `writeChars()`. Another way is `randomAccessFile.writeBytes(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`, since `writeBytes()` can take in `String` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Try writing a new line to the file before anything else, as it will start writing where your last write left off.

Answer (score 0):

new line character has an ASCII value of 10 . You can store this value in in a Byte and then use the "writeBytes" which will result in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String data = "New Line";
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(myFile);
raf.writeBytes("\r\n" + data);
```

This will add a new line (windows style / CRLF) before the "text".